# Requesting data from REST endpoint in loop, works in FF not in chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, firefox

I'm trying to loop through an array of users and get an image from an external rest endpoint for each user in the loop and then set it to that user.

This works great in Firefox, but in Chrome it only gets 1 image and sets it for all the users.

The weird thing is that the `$http` request get's called the correct number of times in Chrome.

Any ideas what's going on here?

```
// Loop through all the users
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.users.length; i++) {
  get_image(i);
}

// Fetches a random image and adds it to a user
function get_image(index) {

  console.log('index = '+index);

// TODO: Something's screwy with this. in FF it loads a new image per user, in chrome it loads the same image for all user
  $http.get('http://uifaces.com/api/v1/random').then(function(response) {
    console.log('in get');  // <-- This line get's called as many times as there are users in my array.
    $scope.users[index].face = response.data.image_urls.normal;
  });
}
```

Comment: Maybe look at the headers?

Comment: `$scope.user[index].face = response.data.image_urls.normal;` seems to miss an `s` shouldn't it be `$scope.users[index]` ?

Comment: If you open chrome dev tools, and go to the network tab and look at the http request responses, are the responses all the same, or different? You could also try and set a breakpoint at `console.log('in get');` just to have a look at everything.

Comment: looks like chrome remember things longer, try busting the cache. that would explain everything and be easy to fix. let's hope so...

Comment: In chrome there is only 1 request to uifaces in the network tab so I can't compare anything. @dandavis are you saying that the request to uifaces is being cache so that it makes 1 request, then the next time it comes across the code for another request, it just says "Oh hey i just made that request. I'll just return the same data? can you provide an example for busting the cache?

Comment: just add, say, "?"+Math.random() to the end of the url...

Comment: That causes no data to come back in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is race condition. I'm not sure, why do it works this way, but i have implemented getting gravatars with this method - https://github.com/caolan/async#each, there is a async version for browser use.